# Jinja HTML Displays Index Number

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have a remote MongoDB that I want to display data via webpage in Flask/Jinja. I am able to iterate through my Mongo docs, but each have a number associated with their location in the dictionary. Any idea on how to simply display the data and NOT the index number?

flask_app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb+srv://example:example@cluster0-zd456.mongodb.net/example?retryWrites=true'
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
   example = mongo.db.collection.find({})
   return render_template("index.html", example=example)
```

index.html:

```
{% for ex in example %}
{{loop.index0}} {{ex['example_name']}}
{% endfor %}
```

index.html OUTPUT:

```
0 Example 
1 Example2
2 Example3
3 Example4
4 Example5
```

The index number also is displayed if I iterate through my collections. For example, if I instead used:

index.html 2:

```
{% for ex in example %}
{{loop.index0}} {{ex}}
{% endfor %}
```

index.html OUTPUT 2:

```
0 {
'_id': ObjectId('5c85fdsf210e245417'), 
'deal_url': 'https://www.example.com/+6+variety+pack', 
'brief_description': 'Variety Pack', 
'image_urls': ['https://www.example.com/images/skupics/crt/example.jpg'], 'images': [{'url': 'https://www.example.com/images/skupics/crt/example.jpg', 'path': 'full/e6b3c4abd87r4jkhfdkjhfc607ee04870f939067a.jpg', 'checksum': '4379fakdhfkjsfhkdjhf571e2eb'}], 
'msrp': '$43.61', 
'number': '14', 
'percent_off': '36% OFF', 
'product_name': 'Example Accessories And Samplers', 
'rating': '87 Rated', 
'sale_ends': '04/22)', 
'sale_price': ' $22.99'
} 

1 {
'_id': ObjectId('5c85fdsf210e245417'), 
'deal_url': 'https://www.example.com/+6+variety+pack', 
'brief_description': 'Variety Pack', 
'image_urls':

etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the index, the indexes of each element will appear. Have you tried to do only this?

```
{% for ex in example %}
{{ex['example_name']}}
{% endfor %}
```

When you do the for you're already iterating in every element `ex`.

Comment: This worked splendidly. I spent soooo much time trying to resolve this! Thank you so much!